# Who am I? A name

Tags: riddle, geography

Okay, here is a who am I puzzle.

> *I am an absolute thing to like*
> *For I got my name from sea to shining sea*
> *But I cannot reach the peace*
> *Without help from the South*
> *And I pull loads of stuff every day*
>
> *That was but I used to*
> *Now I can reach the peace*
> *But I still can't reach Atlantis*
> *Need the pen or the yoke.*
> *Through the city of winds, now...*

Who am I?

**HINT:**

> *The train of the stars ran once on me*
>  *From sea to shining sea.*
>  *From the hubby windy to the western gate*
>  *And not through Santa Fe, see.*

Comment: Hi and welcome to Puzzling, Tzu Li! Might be easier for us if you add a clue of some sort

Comment: Thought it might be a boat or ship as they can't reach Atlantis, but I can't fit it to the rest

Comment: Is the City of Winds Chicago perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the

> Southwest Chief railroad line?

I am an absolute thing to like

> A railroad line

For I got my name from sea to shining sea

> It made a name for itself transporting celebrities in the past

But I cannot reach the peace

> It could not reach the Pacific in the past

Without help from the South

> Without using another train (the Southern Pacific Transportation Company)?

And I pull loads of stuff every day

> Passengers and cargo

That was but I used to

> This was the old train

Now I can reach the peace

> The Pacific Ocean

But I still can't reach Atlantis

> It can’t reach the Atlantic Ocean

Need the pen or the yoke.

> Without needing another form of transportation

Through the city of winds, now...

> The start of the line is Chicago, the Windy City

The train of the stars ran once on me

> The Super Chief train was once called the train of the stars as it travelled Chicago to LA.

From sea to shining sea.

> From Lake Michigan to the Pacific Ocean?

From the hubby windy to the western gate

> From Chicago to Los Angeles

And not through Santa Fe, see.

> The old Super Chief line ran through Santa Fe but the new Southwest Chief does not.

Comment: You're right! But I'd consider improving it; the "pen or the yoke" and "South" might refer to some other companies...

Comment: Hmm...any hints for those? Think I have South..

Answer (score 3):

I am an absolute thing to like

> It's a nice place to travel (Bermuda)

For I got my name from sea to shining sea

> the meaning of the phrase 'From sea to shining sea' is From one coast to another( a line in 'America the Beautiful' song). 
> The name he received is according to the islands whose coastline is one of its vertices.

But I cannot reach the peace
Without help from the South

> In the past, the southern island of the Triangle  -Puerto Rico was under another rule and only in 1953 was it granted international status by the United Nations,On which tourism is a large part of the income and is also nourished by tourists who sail on their way to the island And tourism is possible when there is peace.

And I pull loads of stuff every day

> Some say that it sells magnetic field causes the disappearance transport

That was but I used to
Now I can reach the peace

> Tourism is great in the area

But I still can't reach Atlantis
Need the pen or the yoke.

> It is  located in the Atlantic Ocean,which is named after the Greek mythology in which God  Άτλας (ATLAS)was appointed ruler of Atlantis As Atlantis disappeared under the water, as legend has it, ships and planes disappeared there and were not found,Atlas was punished who had to carry the world on his shoulders -this meaning of yoke.

Through the city of winds, now...

> Zeus, the father of the gods, destroyed the continent with an earthquake or volcanic eruption, because of the greed and selfishness of its inhabitants, and a city that was destroyed is usually called a ghost town or city of winds

I think the answer is:

> Bermuda Triangle

Comment: Seems like I need to brush up on my geography :p